# angr with a golang target

Tags: angr

Here is a very basic golang program:

```
package main
import "fmt"

func main() {
    var s1 string
    fmt.Scanln(&s1)

    if s1=="goodpassword" {
        fmt.Println("Good")
    } else {
        fmt.Println("Wrong")
    }
}
```

I have compiled this program (elf64 linux binary).

I have diasssembled the binary and i have found the addresses of the 2 fmt.Println calls:

```
...
0x00490d4f     lea rax, obj.main.statictmp_1    ; wrong
...
0x00490d99     lea rax, obj.main.statictmp_0    ; good
...
```

Now, i have wrote this python program:

```
import angr
from angr.state_plugins import SimSystemPosix

p = angr.Project('./mybinary')

sm = p.factory.simulation_manager()
sm.explore(find= 0x00490d99, avoid= 0x00490d4f)

print(sm.found[0].posix.dumps(0))
```

I do not understand why angr does not return "goodpassword" string.
I have something wrong but i do not understand what...

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 3):

The Go run time is fairly complicated that symbolic solvers will not run out-of-the-box as-is. You are asking `angr` to figure out everything on it's own which may be feasible for simple and uncomplicated C programs but not for something like Go binaries.

For example, the `fmt.Scanln` function will call multiple Go functions before you reach `libc.read`. Angr has SimProcedures for `read` but not for `fmt.Scanln`. To figure out what `fmt.Scanln` does it has to symbolically execute after which only it may able to discover the dependency between `stdin` and the program output. Symbolically executing `Scanln` is by no way a simple task.

Instead, you should break down the problem in parts which you can ask `angr` to solve. Like if you have identified the buffer where the user input is stored you can mark that as symbolic and instruct `angr` to find the path to the "good password" branch.

Further resources on Go reversing:

- https://r3xnation.wordpress.com/2018/01/11/reversing-go-binaries-part-1/
- https://2016.zeronights.ru/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/GO_Zaytsev.pdf
- https://rednaga.io/2016/09/21/reversing_go_binaries_like_a_pro/

Comment: Thanks. I have identified the buffer but how can i mark it as symbolic and how can i instruct angr to find the good password ?

Comment: @Bob5421 Check [this](https://docs.angr.io/core-concepts/states)

Comment: Thanks i have already read this documentation but there are so much cases i do not understand which one is the good. In fact i want to virtually start my program at the address after the scanf and ask angr to solve password.